# editing an array output at the console

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++ and I'm working on a very simple exercise, but I cannot get it done. I have defined a class named Worker, which has some data (wage and SSN). Then, I have defined two methods to get data from the object (`GetWage()` and `GetSSN()`)

How can I print SSN in the console with dots (like `111.11.1111`)? For example, in my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Worker.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Worker Person1(5000, "111111111");

    cout << "Wage of Person1 is " << Person1.GetWage << "\n"; 
    cout << "SSN of Person1 is " << Person1.GetSSN << "\n"; 

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have for Worker.h

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Worker {

public

    double Wage;
    char   SSN;

    Worker(double wage; char *ssn);

    double GetWage(){
        return Wage;
    }

    char* GetSSN(){
        return SSN;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just write `Worker Person1(5000, "111.11.1111");` and change `char SSN;` to `std::string SSN;`. Finally, adjust the member functions and give a body and initializer list to the constructor.

Comment: The code you posted cannot be the code you're actually using.  It doesn't even compile.  Get it to compile first, or ask the question of why it's not compiling.  Also, `char SSN` is incorrect.  And why are you inputing the SSN without the dots in the first place? If it's acceptable to take the SSN without dots, then your object's constructor should probably be configuring it in the representation that is most appropriate for what it represents.  (Don't ssn's use hyphens, though?)

Comment: of course it is not going to compile, I have not provided all my methods here because they are irrelevant for what I have asked. 40two replied a nice note, you could simply have added something constructive to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of basic errors in ur code..
Like dis one..

```
    cout << "Wage of Person1 is " << Person1.GetWage << "\n";
```

It should actually be

```
    cout << "Wage of Person1 is " << Person1.GetWage() << "\n";
```

Define ur constructor, you have just declared it.
Just a work around ur messed up code.

worker.h

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Worker {

    public:

        double Wage;
        std::string   SSN;

        Worker(double wage, std::string ssn){
            Wage = wage;
            SSN = ssn;
        }

        double GetWage(){
            return Wage;
        }

        std::string GetSSN(){
           return SSN;
        }
 };
```

And Main.cpp

```
    #include "worker.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
       Worker Person1(5000, "111111111");
       cout << "Wage of Person1 is " << Person1.GetWage() << "\n";
       cout << "SSN of Person1 is " << Person1.GetSSN() << "\n";
       return 0;
    }
```

Remove syntactical errors in your code before posting it!
And as the others have stated..Just write

```
    Worker Person1(5000, "111.11.1111");
```

instead of

```
    Worker Person1(5000, "111111111");
```

Comment: yes, but using "111.11.1111" instead of just editing it to show the dots in a console, would not be a disadvantage because I would need memory space for the dots?

Comment: If u want to insert dots in ur SSN string see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/)    Eg:      std::string s = "111111111";      s.insert(s.begin()+3, '.');